# How to reorder input field

Tags: seam, auto-generate

I haved generated simple CRUD application from seam-gen using seam generate-ui command, but the edit page for insert data into database was genated and orderd by name.

For example if entity class contain `name,lastname` and `age`. Seam-gen will generate and ordered field list to age,lastname, and name (order by name).

The question is how do I config to reorder those input field to my requirement. such as from `age,lastname,name` to `name, lastname` and `age.`

Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you mean.
Do you mean the list that is returned from resultList is ordered according to the wrong column?

If that is the case you can override the default ejbql in your SomeTableList EntityQuery

```
@Override
public String getEjbql() {
  return "select s from SomeTable s order by s.name";
}
```

You can also use the

```
@OrderBy
```

annotation in your entity
Look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/jpa/resources/toplink-jpa-annotations.html#OrderBy) for more detail

Answer (score 0):

You should write your custom order in <YOUR_APP_HOME>/resources/seamgen.
reveng.xml. [Here](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/tools/reference/en/html/reverseengineering.html) you can see how you can edit this file. After editing, you can generate your User Interface in the <SEAM_HOME> directory by using

```
seam generate-ui restart
```

regards,